# Error after updating .net Core 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I created new asp.net core web api project and updated to 1.1. I am getting following errors:

1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`   WebApplication1 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets
2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.

Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:   WebApplication1 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  262

Please advice!

Comment: Please show your: `globals.json` (from solution root), `project.json`, list of subdirectories under `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the steps of [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/).

Probably you will have to add this code:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version":  "1.1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! This fixed the issue for me. For whatever reason, my `project.json` file had `"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0"` in the *dependencies* section; I removed that.
I really need to learn more about the actual implementation of all this. But since `project.json` is going away... hopefully I can wait until there's just one new model to learn. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a runtimes section in your project.json file.
In your project.json try to add the following section:

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": { }
  }
```